# Access violation -> CreateVertexShader

Tags: c++, visual-studio, shader, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I am playing around with DirectX and I got to the point where I have to play around with shaders among other things. Because D3DX does not exist anymore( :P ) I have to use D3DCompile to compile the shader. I use this piece of code:

```
D3DCompile(//Vertex Shader
    L"shaders.hlsl",//Pointer to shader data
    sizeof(L"shaders.hlsl"),//Shader size
    NULL,//OPTIONAL, name used in error msgs
    NULL,//OPTIONAL,  An array of NULL-terminated macro definitions(wut?)
    D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE,//OPTIONAL, DONT PASS NULL, pass D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE which is the defualt
    "VShader",//Name of shaders starting function
    "vs_5_0",//Shader target, vs_5_0 for vertex shader and ps_5_0 for pixel shader
    NULL,//Shader compile options --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg615083(v=vs.85).aspx, set to NULL
    0,//Shader effect compile options --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg615084(v=vs.85).aspx, set to 0
    &VS,//Pointer to var that will hold shader
    NULL//OPTIONAL, Pointer to var that holds error messages
    );
```

And as you can see I point to `VS` where the compiled code will be outputted. I then use this code to encapsulate the shaders in a shader object:

```
m_pDevice->CreatePixelShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
```

Where `VS` is initialized as `ID3D10Blob *VS` and `pVS` is initialized as `ID3D11VertexShader *pVS`

When I run it(With the rest of the code associated with it) I get a `Unhandled expression` that is

```
Unhandled exception at 0x009188FC in Hello_DirectX11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

and when I break out it breaks at the code above when I encapsulated the shader in a shader object.

---

How do I fix this/what is wrong?

Also are there any good ways to debug this kind of stuff with VS 2013?

Comment: `sizeof(L"shaders.hlsl")` returns the size of the `string` "shaders.hlsl", not the size of the data inside the file AFAIK. And this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx says you should use `D3DCompileFromFile` instead.

Comment: Not to mention, that is a wide character string literal. You do not pass he name of a shader file to this function, you pass the actual shader text and then the length of the shader text. It expects the shader to be encoded in ASCII, so `L"..."` would be wrong even if it were not the name of a file.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Could you give me an example? I tried just putting the shader data in a var and I still got an error. I also tried using D3DCompileFromFile and I got the same result. When I looked at the HRESULT it was an error called E_FAIL which doesn't tell em anything. Is there anyway to debug a function with multiple variables so I can determine which input it actually causing the problem.

Comment: @NoahHuppert The above are just things that I noticed as a C++ programmer. I can't really help you with DirectX, that's why I commented instead of replying. Sorry mate.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Ok, ty. Would you know how to debug functions in c++? Also I believe I will keep using D3DCompile because on the D3DCompileFromFile page it says `You can use this API to develop your Windows Store apps, but you can't use it in apps that you submit to the Windows Store.`

Comment: @NoahHuppert you can't debug a function that you don't have the code of. You can however check the address of the function in the debugger, maybe it's not bound to anything? You should probably create a new question with the fixes and data you got in these comments and various other places.